# svn Can't set position pointer in file

Tags: svn, svnadmin, fsfs

I'm having an issue with an svn repository that has been working just fine up to now.

I am getting the error

```
svnadmin: Can't set position pointer in file 'repository/db/revs/0/783': Invalid argument
```

for example when I run

```
svnadmin verify
```

Other general symptoms include not being able to checkout, update, commit etc.

Any help much appreciated

thanks!
Peter

Answer (score 3):

OK... I just had this problem and was able to fix it.  I'm using FSFS.  The last good revision I had was Revision Number 88.  Revision 89 was the one that was broken.

1. I copied the repository and named it `repository-2018-10-18-broken`.  Absolutely do this first!!!
2. I deleted the following files in the original repository:

/repository/db/revs/0/89

/repository/db/revprops/0/89

/repository/db/transactions/89*.*

3. Using my trusty text editor, I then edited the file `/repository/db/current` and changed the `89` to `88`.  I left in the trailing new line.

This worked like a charm.  I can't say it will work for anyone else, but I don't see why it wouldn't.  It seems like it effectively, truly, deletes the bad revision.

Comment: thank you so much. your solution worked successfully at my windows svn server.

Answer (score 1):

When the same problem occurred we were able to track it down to an individual folder which had files that were moved incorrectly.

Other folders allowed committing and updating, only when including that folder did we get the message of being unable to set the pointer.

**The solution** was:

1. Remove the offending folder from the SVN (ignore, recursive)
2. Add the folder again.
3. Commit the folder.

This seemed to fix whatever was wrong.

With more trial and error I guess the problem could be tracked to the file[s] that were responsible, but in this case we stopped at folder level.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find was to make a copy of my repository as follows

```
svnadmin create newrepo
svnadmin dump -r 0:783 repository | svnadmin load newrepo
mv repository repository_corrupted
mv newrepo repository
```

After this, an svn cleanup was generally required in users checked out directories

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way ever for Can't set position pointer in file:**

I did this way:

1. Go to **Parent directory(Folder)** of **Project**.
2. Press **Right click**
3. Press on **TortoiseSVN** then Press **Clean up...**
4. Clean up dialog would appear automatically
5. Select `Clean up working copy status`, `Break locks`, `Fix time stamps`, `Vacuum pristine copies`, `Refresh shell overlays`, `Include externals`
6. Pres **OK**

Check the screen shots for your reference.

**First step:**

[image]

**Second step:**

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with some files. When I drilled down to the folder in question the revision file repository/db/revs/89 was a zero file. I guess the problem might be due to some hardware failure or power interruption (the repos is on a usb drive). The way I fixed that is to copy 88 to 89 and then I was able to submit the change again.